# Scraping Walmart.com with Scrapy and getting Generic Error 500

Tags: python, scrapy, akamai

I'm new to Python and Scrapy, I've been scraping walmart.com with somewhat positive results.

It was working thru the week and even 25 hours ago however last night I began getting this response, it doesnt appear as an error in scrapy this is what is scraped and returned via txt file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
    <title>Omnivore Walmart</title>

</head>
<body id="WalmartBodyId" class="WalmartMainBody SimpleMode">



<!-- SiteCatalyst code version: H.23.3
Copyright 1996-2009 Adobe, Inc. All Rights Reserved
More info available at http://www.omniture.com
-->


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var s_account="walmartcom";
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src=" https://secure.walmartimages.com/webanalytics/wmStat/wmStat.jsp"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var omni = {
"adid" : s_omni.getQueryParam('adid'),
"fbref" : s_omni.getQueryParam('fb_ref'),
"sourceid" : s_omni.getQueryParam('sourceid'),
"povid" : s_omni.getQueryParam('povid'),
"findingMethod" : s_omni.getQueryParam('findingMethod'),
getCampaignId : function() {
if(this.adid) { return this.adid; }
else if (this.fbref) { return this.fbref.split('_')[1]; }
else if (this.sourceid){ return this.sourceid; }
else { return ''; }
}
};
s_omni.pageName="Akamai Error 500:https://www.walmart.com/ip/Pringles-Loaded-Baked-Potato-Potato-Crisps-5-5-oz-Canister/144650857";
s_omni.channel="Walmart.com";
s_omni.campaign=omni.getCampaignId();
s_omni.prop1="Akamai Error";
s_omni.prop2="Akamai Error 500";
s_omni.prop48="Akamai 500:Generic Error - AKAMAI REFERENCE ERROR NO:3.1be3ab42.1510509312.48a15f11"; 

var s_code=s_omni.t();if(s_code) document.write(s_code);
</script>

<br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Error Page</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Could not connect to server</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I've researched and most think it's rare that 500 means blocked/banned, is it possible I've tweaked something or can tweak something to generate results again?

any help would be greatly appreciated, I've tried a different product on WM.com and get the same, I can reach it thru browser without any problem.

Comment: Walmart has figured out you are scraping their site and banned you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scraper has probably been banned from the site, because you were either detected scraping or were malicious in other ways (e.g. sending too many requests per minute ¹, not following robots.txt).

Since you say that it still worked several hours ago, I assume that the ban is IP based. You can now do the following:

- are all requests from scrapy banned or is it possible to perform a few when you start your scraper and then after a few requests it stops working?
- see if you can reach Walmart.com or `https://www.walmart.com/ip/Pringles-Loaded-Baked-Potato-Potato-Crisps-5-5-oz-Canister/144650857` from a normal browser, but the same IP (if it is on a server, you could use `curl` or `wget` or create an SSH tunnel from your local PC to your server)

  - if this works, the ban is not only based on IP, so you could try to change scrapy's `USER_AGENT` and see if it works again
- try your same scrapy setup from another PC (but only shortly) and see if it works (if yes, then the ban includes at least the IP)

Next, you should reduce your crawling rate. I assume you were crawling too aggressively. In most cases it's enough to just reduce the crawling rate. However, for walmart I could also believe that they have more advanced measures like detecting robots from URL visit patterns and the like (I mean, maybe walmart could even detect you if you do only request per minute only).

Some ideas to circumvent banning issues:

- reduce crawling rate with `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` or the `AUTOTHROTTLE_*` settings
- use a crawling cluster with IP rotation

  - scrapinghub offers this, but it's not for free, and since scrapinghub is used by lots of people, their proxies might have the same issues
- do not use the default user agent of scrapy (but I assume you already changed that, at least it is not a problem in your situation now)

### Footnotes

¹ yes, per minute. In normal web crawling we try to have a delay of a few seconds for the most websites. Some use the formula `factor * response-time-of-website` in polite crawling where the factor differs a bit, but is always > 1. This means that the delay time according to this formula will also usually be > 1 second, I have even heard of factors around 30, meaning that delay time could be 15 seconds or more.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of, I didn't intend to maliciously crawl I was a little too aggressive testing. I appreciate your input